# Git push and pull not working, edited code isn't merging with existing repo

Tags: linux, github, linux-mint

I'm trying to push some changed to an existing github repo. I cloned the repo onto my computer, changed a few lines in some files from it and then tried git push origin master. It returns this:

```
To https://github.com/judah-tw/myrepo.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/judah-tw/myrepo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I try git pull origin master and this shows up:

```
warning: no common commits
remote: Enumerating objects: 23, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (23/23), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (10/10), done.
remote: Total 85 (delta 19), reused 13 (delta 13), pack-reused 62
Unpacking objects: 100% (85/85), done.
From https://github.com/judah-tw/myrepo.git
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
Auto-merging readme.txt
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in readme.txt
Auto-merging main.c
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in main.c
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

git merge returns this:

```
error: merge is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
```

What does it mean to fix them in the work tree? I followed the instructions on https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/ but they're not working for me.

Comment: You have conflicts. You need to resolve the conflicts by editing the `readme.txt` and `main.c` files.  Then do `git add readme.txt main.c` then `git commit`.

Comment: @RedCricket What do you mean conflicts? The files are different than whats on the repo yes, thats the point is to push the changed files and update the old ones on the repo. Pushing files that are the same wouldn't change the repo at all